# Map Server 4 Windows problem

Tags: mapserver, ms4w, interface

How do I display shape files with a google-like interface in a web application?

I found a tutorial at http://spatialhorizons.com/2007/05/19/mapserver-1-10-minute-tutorial/
which uses an earlier version of map server (the tutorial uses v2.2.6 and I am using v3.0.6) and followed it with no problems up to the second to last point.  I know I have set up map server correctly since when I navigate to localhost in my browser I see the welcome screen.  However, when I select the ka-map sample interface link I get the error: "The requested URL /kamap was not found on this server."

Could someone please advise about where I am going wrong?

Comment: You better off uploading shapefiles (convert them to KML) to fusion tables - shapefiles are too slow for web useage.

Comment: @Mapperz - using fusion would place my shapefiles on top of Google Maps.  Unfortunately options like Google Maps and Open Street Maps are not accurate enough (not geocoded, not all street names, outdated satellite imagery, etc) in my part of the world for the project I am working on.  I am also hesitant to use Google/OSM because of their 'anyone can edit it' nature.  I can edit OSM and download it/ or create accurate maps in ArcGIS.  I am looking for a way to translate the ArcGIS/downloaded OSM maps to the pretty interface that is displayed by Google/OSM

Comment: What do you mean by 'google like interface'? Kamap is an old and obsolete technology. Nowadays Leaflet and OpenLayers are used as Clientside APIs